# How to draw a nice diagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices

How to typeset a nice looking diagonal matrix? I find myself, once again, fiddling with phantoms and running raiseboxes to get an aesthetic result. This kind of micromanagement is bad practice, but why does the default look so bad and is there a better way? [image: Two diagonal matrices side by side]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \operatorname{diag} x &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \ddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & x_n
  \end{bmatrix}
  &
  \operatorname{diag} x &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \raisebox{-0.4ex}{\(\ddots\)}\rule[3.4ex]{0pt}{0pt} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & x_n \rule[3.4ex]{0pt}{0pt}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First, use `\DeclareMathOperator` if you use "diag" many times in the document.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is not with `bmatrix`, but with `\ddots`.

Comment: `\def\arraystretch{1.5}%` outside align or inside equation

Answer (score 7):

A TABstack alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath% STACK MATRIX IN MATH MODE
\setstacktabbedgap{10pt}% INTER-COLUMN GAP SIZE
\setstackgap{L}{1.5\baselineskip}% INTER-ROW BASELINESKIP
\newcommand\cddots{\raisebox{-1pt}{$\ddots$}}
\begin{document}
\[  \operatorname{diag} x =
  \bracketMatrixstack{
    x_1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \cddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & x_n
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

While not needed for diagonal matrices of the type portrayed by the OP, the package has a `\fixTABwidth{<T or F>}` declaration to fix all column widths to the largest found in the matrix.  That can be helpful if there are wide matrix entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath% STACK MATRIX IN MATH MODE
\setstacktabbedgap{10pt}% INTER-COLUMN GAP SIZE
\setstackgap{L}{1.5\baselineskip}% INTER-ROW BASELINESKIP
\newcommand\cddots{\raisebox{-1pt}{$\ddots$}}
\begin{document}
\fixTABwidth{T}
\[  \operatorname{diag} x =
  \bracketMatrixstack{
    x_1 & 0 & 12345\\
    0 & \cddots & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & x_n
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could if you liked to use the package `nicematrix`. Between the many options defined by `nicematrix` there is columns-width, where you can fit the two brackets of the matrix in function of the values into it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent,nullify-dots}
\begin{document}
\[\operatorname{diag} x =\begin{bmatrix}[columns-width = 3mm]
x_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & x_n 
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Another possibility using `columns-width = auto`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent,nullify-dots}
\begin{document}


\[\operatorname{diag} x =\begin{bmatrix}[columns-width = auto]
x_1 & 436436 & 67676\\
0 & \ddots & 0 \\
8778 & 0 & x_n 
\end{bmatrix}\]


\end{document}
```